# Non-overlap time in auxiliary contacts on contactors

Tags: specifications, contactor

As long as I have tested, my standard contactors such as Schneider TeSys [LC1D32A](https://www.se.com/ww/en/product/LC1D32M7/tesys-deca-contactor-3p3-no-ac3-ac3e-440-v-32-a-220-v-ac-coil/) are equipped with (13-14) NO and (21-22) NC contacts, which never close simultaneously.

For this device, the auxiliary contacts are specified as having a Non-Overlap Time of 1.5 ms, both for energization and de-energization of the (NO) contacts.

> Auxiliary Contacts Type: 
> Type mechanically linked 1 NO + 1 NC conforming to IEC 60947-5-1 
> Type mirror contact 1 NC conforming to IEC 60947-4-1

> Non-Overlap Time 
> 1.5 ms on de-energisation between NC and NO contact 
> 1.5 ms on energisation between NC and NO contact

Does the IEC 60947 or some other code have any specifications for this Non-Overlap Time for Mechanically Linked Contact Elements?